make: execute recipe when the recipe of a dependency failed
I'm running make with the "--keep-going" option (by default not, but it's an option in our macros to run the whole build which uses make): This tells make to continue to consider the other prerequisites of the pending targets, remaking them if necessary, before it gives up and returns nonzero status
What I experience it that when the recipe of a dependency fails, the recipe of the target is NOT executed at all. I would like it to be executed anyway, is that possible ?
The explain my question more indept:
program.exe: program.txt module.linkable
   link to exe

module.linkable: module.txt
   compile to linkable

When the rule for "module.linkable", so the compile, fails the rule for target program.exe is NOT executed ... but I would like it to be executed anyway when using the "--keep-going" option.
FYI, also using the --ignore-errors option didn't work for me.
Followup: I did find a solution. In the compile/link rule an "exit 100" was done in case the compile/link program failed. When I change that to "exit 0" then it works.
"exit 100" is the default of course, but I can start my build macro with a special parameter in which case make will do the "exit 0".

Are you sure --ignore-errors didn't give you the desired behaviour?  I think it should (unless I've misunderstood the question).

@G.M. yes I'm sure, because I tested it


What I experience it that when the recipe of a dependency fails, the recipe of the target is NOT executed at all.

Yes, that is make's behavior, regardless of --keep-going.  It is not sensible in make's model of the universe to update a target whose dependencies are out of date and cannot be brought up to date.  The --keep-going option instructs GNU make to build what it can subject to that constraint, instead of quitting as soon as any recipe fails (there are often multiple targets to be built that do not depend on each other).

I would like it to be executed anyway, is that possible ?

I don't know any make option that would provide for this.  Again, it is inconsistent with make's operating model.
You can persuade the shell to ignore errors, however, so you could conceivably do this with a submake. But that is nasty.  You would be better off restructuring your build so that your targets don't have false dependencies.
If you want to try the submake option anyway, then it would look something like this:
.PHONY: several_things_that_might_fail

several_things_that_might_fail:
        $(MAKE) target1_that_may_fail || :
        $(MAKE) target2_that_may_fail || :
        $(MAKE) target3_that_may_fail || :

The || : is a shell idiom for quashing failure status of a command.
Note that one of the consequences of using a submake is that each make execution does its own analysis of the targets to be built, with the result that across all the make runs, some targets might be built more than once.  This is one of the things that makes the approach nasty.

thanks. The submake option doesn't work for me as my targets are different for each application the makefile is used with. My rules are also not specific for one program, but more to the extension.

Then, @kahoona, make is probably not the tool you're looking for.  In fact, "my targets are different for each application the makefile is used with" itself tells me that make is not the tool you are looking for.  make's is not a scripting language.  Makefiles are project-specific.  One does not (should not) use the same makefile to build multiple applications, except inasmuch as that makefile makes specific provisions for each one, or else is customized, separately, for each one.  Possibly you want a shell script, instead, maybe with a little make on the back end.

Another way to have make ignore errors, that doesn't require a submake or anything like that, is to prefix the command with -.  Of course, this means make will always ignore any failure from that command and treat it as successful regardless of the exit code.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html

You could use a make variable and conditionals instead of a standard make option:
ifeq ($(FORCE),)
program.exe: program.txt module.linkable
else
program.exe:
endif
   link to exe

And then:
$ make --keep-going program.exe
<failure but buildable prerequisites done>
$ make program.exe FORCE=1
<ignore prerequisites>

